# Programmatically creating Faunadb child database

Tags: multi-tenant, faunadb

Hi I am new in Faunadb and trying a multi-tenancy app. There is option of creating child databases from fauna shell. But my thinking is when a user is signed up, a child database with that username will create automatically.

I searched in there documentation but got no idea. Is it possible from frontend JS libraries such as React, Vue or from API in Nodejs?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can programatically create a child database using `CreateDatabase`. Two things are important to note here:

- The key you use for creating the child db must have the `admin` [role](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/security/keys?lang=javascript#admin-role), so you'd want to do it from a secure backend node server.
- Which database you connect to in fauna is defined by which key you use to connect, so you must generate and use another key for the new child database.

This is how the code might look:

```js
// Connect to the parent database
const parentFauna = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY
})

// Create child database and retrieve a new key for it
const { secret } = await parentFauna.query(
  Do(
    CreateDatabase({
      name: "example"
    }),
    CreateKey({
      database: Database("example"),
      role: "server"
    })
  )
)

// You can now connect to the child database
const childFauna = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: secret
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JS driver](https://github.com/fauna/faunadb-js) (it's not framework-specific) to create the child DB and set up its schema using fauna's [Create* functions](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/cheat_sheet).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already applied these two in react app and successful in creating main database. No luck for child database. Have you any example for this. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have code I can share. Besides I don't create child DBs automatically during sign up.
So where is the problem: CreateDatabase, CreateKey, CreateCollection, CreateIndex?

Comment: Yes CreateDatabase. How will I use CreateDatabase for creating child database under a specific parent database or active database? I didn't find any code or solution yet.

Comment: Ok, you need to understand that the secret/token is DB specific. Also, most FQL functions act on the secret's DB exclusively. So you 1- connect to the parent DB, 2- CreateDatabase, 3- CreateKey, 4- use the key you got in #3 to create a new client that can prepare the child's schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it and inform you the update.

Comment: Any update on this @DilwarHossainNoorChandan ?  I'm also having your exact problem.

Comment: @VirgarPoulsen no luck.